# Is there a dpkg -C program which actually checks if the files are present in the filesystem?

Tags: debian

In other words, read the dpkg database to see if some of the files are missing. I accidentally the system with rm -rf and then quickly hit ^C when I realised what I was doing but I don't know what's missing. It seems to be perfectly up and running so I just want to make sure.

dpkg -C is way too quick so I checked with strace and it doesn't seem to actually audit the files, it just runs a function over the database to say which packages aren't completely installed (might not be true if it was just an error in the configure script).